# handle redirected response with proper parser

Tags: python, redirect, scrapy

I am crawling a site with scrapy. The `parse` method first extracts all the category links and then dispatch a request with callback to `parse_category`.

The problem is if any of the category has one product it redirects to the products page. And my `parse_category` fails to recognize this page.

Now how do I parse that redirectted category page with product page parser?

Here is an example.

1. `parse` finds 3 category pages.

   1. `http://example.com/products/samsung`
   2. `http://example.com/products/dell`
   3. `http://example.com/products/apple`
2. `pare_category` calls all those pages. Each returns a html page with list of product. But `apple` has one single product `iMac 27"`. So it redirects to `http://example.com/products/apple/imac_27`. This is a product page.The category parse fails to parse it.

I need the product parse method `parse_product` should be called in this scenario. How do I do that?

I can add some logic in my parse_category method and call parse_product. I dont want it. I want scrapy will do it. But yes, I'll give url patterns or any other info necessary.

Here is the code.

```
class ExampleSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = u'example.com'
    allowed_domains = [u'www.example.com']
    start_urls = [u'http://www.example.com/category.aspx']

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        anchors = hxs.select('/xpath')
        for anchor in anchors:
            yield Request(urljoin(get_base_url(response), anchor), callback=self.parse_category)

    def parse_category(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

        products = hxs.select(products_xpath).extract()
        for url in products:
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_product)


    def parse_product(self, response):
        # product parsing ...
        pass
```

Comment: @alecxe I dont think code is necessary here. I have described my problem very well. The problem is not about the code. Still I give you my simplified spider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can opt to write a [middleware](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html) which implements the `process_response` method. Whenever your response is for a product URL instead of a category, create a [copy of the Request object](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.copy) and [change the callback function](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request.replace) to your product parser.

In the end, return the new `Request` object from the middleware. Note: You *might* need to set `dont_filter` to `True` for the new `Request` to ensure the DupeFilter doesn't filter the Request.